# How to include string attributes in the cell data of a StructuredGrid using vtk's XML format?

Tags: xml, vtk, paraview

I have been trying to include string attributes into the CellData of a StructuredGrid cell using vtk's XML format.
I want to include an attribute named "Container" with value "AoS" for the cell defined using following xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<VTKFile byte_order="LittleEndian" type="StructuredGrid" version="0.1">
  <StructuredGrid WholeExtent="0 1 0 1 0 1">
    <Piece Extent="0 1 0 1 0 1">
      <PointData/>
      <CellData Scalars="DomainId" Fields="Container">
        <DataArray type="Int32" Name="DomainId" format="ascii">
          0
        </DataArray>
        <DataArray type="String" Name="Container" format="ascii">
         AoS
        </DataArray>
      </CellData>
      <Points>
        <DataArray type="Float32" NumberOfComponents="3" format="ascii">
          0 0 0
          2 0 0
          0 4 0
          2 4 0
          0 0 3
          2 0 3
          0 4 3
          2 4 3
        </DataArray>
      </Points>
    </Piece>
  </StructuredGrid>
</VTKFile>
```

When trying to display this cell in Paraview, I am getting following error:
*Cannot read cell data array "Container" from PointData in piece 0. The data array in the element is too short*

The CellData attribute "Fields" I used in the xml code was just a wild guess and may not even exist. Moving the Container to "Scalars" does not work and I could not find another appropriate CellData attribute to put it in.

What I want to see in Paraviews SpreadsheetView is something like this:
[Example created using legacy vtk format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtzKl.png)

I have tried to solve this for several hours. What I don't know is, which CellData attribute is designated for strings, if DataArray is the right object to use and if yes, which attributes it requires.
Alternatively I tried using StringArray instead of DataArray but could not make it work either.

I also tried to use FieldData to include the string attributes but again without any success.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your string as a null-terminated list of ascii char:

```
    <CellData>
      <Array type="String" Name="Container" format="ascii">
       65 111 83 0 
      </Array>
    </CellData>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This let me display the attribute.